# Check if key has been pressed Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests and I'm using selenium to run them. I'm trying to check if the Alt key has been pressed. If it has been pressed I'm trying to do a key up on Alt.

However when I run this snippet of code it gets as far as `cki = Console.ReadKey(true);` and then just hang until it timesout. Not sure why this is happening on this line. My code is as follows.

```
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

            while (true)
            {
                action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0)
                {
                    action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().Perform();
                }


          }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I've never done this in `Selenium`, normally you would check if a key was pressed with this:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
```

This is in the `System.Windows.Input` namespace.

`Console.ReadKey(true);` pauses the program until a user presses a key, and then it'll read that key. In this case you don't have a user manually pressing a key, so the program just stays paused forever.

IMO it seems like your current `if` statement should work as well if you get rid of your `ReadKey` line, but again selenium might be pressing keys in a way these functions can't detect... Let me know if getting rid of `ReadKey` works, or the above works. If not maybe there is an alternate selenium solution.